# What about blackfish database

Tags: database, blackfish

I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445357/best-database-for-small-applications-and-tools) about database selection for small projects, but no one selected or mentioned Blackfish.
I am using it for a while and I like it, to some point better than SQLserver.
Id like to know other experiences with it, problems, limitations, tools to manage it being built.

Answer (score 1):

There are several (small) databases, so would be exceptional if they were all mentioned.

Maybe you could provide some more information on [blackfish](http://www.codegear.com/products/blackfish).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is popular for open source languages (PHP, Java, etc).  For .NET systems, people go with SQL Server Express Edition - Which is free.